# Different tokenizers gives the same input_ids to same tokens

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, huggingface-tokenizers

I am training a tokenizer and use huggingface for pretrained models. I train a tokenizer using XLM-roberta-base and it gives input_id = 224 to token 'size'. When I changed XLM-roberta-base with another tokenizer, it also gives input_id = 224 to token 'size'. Is that normal ? Wouldn't it supposed to give different ID to token. I mean what are the odds of that happening?

```
pretrained_tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('some tokenizer')
vocab_size = 52_000
tokenizer = pretrained_tokenizer.train_new_from_iterator(training_corpus, vocab_size)

txt = 'merhaba size hatta merhabalar size'
tokense = tokenizer(txt)['input_ids']
    ==>[0, 1353, 224, 16616, 9361, 224, 2]

pretrained_tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('some another tokenizer')
vocab_size = 52_000
tokenizer = pretrained_tokenizer.train_new_from_iterator(training_corpus, vocab_size)

txt = 'merhaba size hatta merhabalar size'
tokense = tokenizer(txt)['input_ids']
    ==>[0, 1353, 224, 16616, 9361, 224, 2]
```

both ids are same and I don't think thats right.

Comment: It is common to reuse the tokenizers to train a different models.

Comment: So thats normal to have same ids for same tokens with different models ?

Comment: If you have the exact model name and the models are open sources, it's possible to trace back the model's `config.json` and `vocab.txt` to verify that the tokenizers are the same.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that both models are using the same tokenization algorithm (e.g BPE), so they would give the same results. Or if they were using different algorithms, it could be that the word you are showing here "size", appeared in the training data so early before the two algorithms could have a mismatch of tokenization decisions (try to verify that by looking at a late index in both tokenizers e.g 30000 or something)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).